# touch: cannot touch 'Dockerfile': Permission denied

Tags: python, django, docker, web, docker-toolbox

I am using the latest version of docker toolbox on windows 10 home and I am getting this problem everytime I run this command I get this error

```
$ touch Dockerfile                                                                                                      touch: cannot touch 'Dockerfile': Permission denied
```

I have been running it in docker quickstart terminal but I've also tried running the it in command prompt and also in command prompt in admistartor mode the error I get there is
'touch' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Need a little bit more detail. Are you running the touch command from Windows Command Prompt? If so, maybe try running the command prompt as an administrator.

Comment: I am using it in docker quikstart terminal but I've also tried it in Windows command prompt in adminstrator and non-adminstrator mode and the error I get in cmd is ('touch' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.)

Comment: There's no equivalent command for touch in cmd.

Answer (score 1):

Touch isn't a command in CMD.

```
fsutil file createnew {filename}  {requiredSize}
```

Will perform a similar function if you're looking to create an empty file.

Answer (score 1):

it seems that docker toolbox is deprecated now, try to create an instance of wsl subsystem and run docker

Answer (score 0):

Download Git bash or mingw, and coreutils such as `touch` and`tee` will work fine inside them.